Is Auto-save feature required after user clears forms
My question is specific to mobile app where we have list of forms and save as a draft option.
I am confused on one of the scenarios mentioned below

User opens a draft form with previously filled values.

User clicks “Clear form” button at the top right corner of the form when opened and confirms Yes to clear the form. Basically, resetting everything to a BLANK form.

User go back to Online Form list then reopen the draft form

The old values will still be populated. Should it be like this or should we remove draft too when user clears the form? What do you suggest from UX point of view?


Thanks everyone in advance.
Shobha

You have mentioned a list of forms. Is the 'Clear Form' particular to one of those forms or does it reset everything?

Sorry, I should have been more clearer. "Clear form" is a button at the top right corner when the form is opened. when user clicked on it, we show a pop up saying, "Are u sure to clear this form?" option Yes will clear the form. It just reset everything.

Since you have confirmation pop up before the reset, there is no need to retain the old values. A message can be added in the confirmation pop up that doing this will reset the entire form to make it very clear to the user about the action. Saving the draft even if it is blank should not be an issue because a record for that user already exists. If a new user opens a new form and closes the form without entering any data, in that case, there is no need to create a new record or save a draft. You may also want to confirm which works better for the users 'Clear Form' or 'Reset Form'.

Thanks for clarifying, Ren.
